# Embed webpage in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

My teammate is writing a form, she could use Libgdx input but prefers to write an html form.

Is there a way to write php/html or jsp form and embed it libgdx? or use ifram or similar to display it? And when the user submits, he gets redirected to Gamescreen

Comment: You can use [platform specific code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code) to open a web page but then, this will be outside LibGDX afaik. I guess your browser will start up on the specific platform and load the page. I don't think this is possible without some serious hacking, coding your own web parser that interacts with your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far away, it's not possible. The only thing that you can do is to make a link to an URL. But it will opened in the device default browser.

For more infos: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Networking -> Gdx.net.openURI(String URI)